# How to correctly pad and align a displaystyle inline equation in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I've got the following code in a document and am at a loss trying to figure out how I can correctly pad the cells and/or align the equations correctly.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ |X|l| }
    \hline
    \textbf{Measurement} & \textbf{Equation} \\
    \hline \hline
    Euclidean distance between the shape model parameters vector for all landmarks $b$ and without the current landmark $b'$ & $\|b-b'\|$ \\
    \hline
    Average point-wise distance between the matched shape for all landmarks $\bar{x}$ and without the current landmark $\bar{x'}$ & $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{3(m-1)}\bar{x}_i-\bar{x'}_i}{3(m-1)}$\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Landmark influence measurements.}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: Not so nice looking table]

Whereas I'd much prefer something like this:

[image: Much better looking table]

As you can see, the differences are the vertical padding of the left column and the alignment of the equations in the right column. Can someone point me in the proper direction on this one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We redefine the `X` column type to be of `m` type instead of `p`:

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
```

and create a new column type `M` with horizontal and vertical centering:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.7cm}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.7cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ |X|M| }
    \hline
    \textbf{Measurement} & \textbf{Equation} \\
    \hline \hline
    Euclidean distance between the shape model parameters vector for all landmarks $b$ and without the current landmark $b'$ & $\|b-b'\|$ \\
    \hline
    Average point-wise distance between the matched shape for all landmarks $\bar{x}$ and without the current landmark $\bar{x'}$ & $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{3(m-1)}\bar{x}_i-\bar{x'}_i}{3(m-1)}$\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Landmark influence measurements.}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you still want "Equation" to be left aligned use `\multicolumn`:

```
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Equation}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.7cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ |X|M| }
    \hline
    \textbf{Measurement} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Equation}} \\
    \hline \hline
    Euclidean distance between the shape model parameters vector for all landmarks $b$ and without the current landmark $b'$ & $\|b-b'\|$ \\
    \hline
    Average point-wise distance between the matched shape for all landmarks $\bar{x}$ and without the current landmark $\bar{x'}$ & $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{3(m-1)}\bar{x}_i-\bar{x'}_i}{3(m-1)}$\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Landmark influence measurements.}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You've certainly helped me along my way and answered my question, thanks a lot. Could you clarify why this works? How did you determine the value 2.7cm? And why did alignment of the equations solve the padding issue on the left as well?

Comment: @Korijn `2.7cm` is found by hand (`2.6cm` gives bad boxes). The padding issue is solved by `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll let "Equation" align with its contents. :)

Answer (score 5):

Package `tabularx` maps its column type `X` internally to `p` columns. This can be changed to vertically centered `m` columns of package `array` by redefining `\tabularxcolumn`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ |X|>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}| }
    \hline
    \textbf{Measurement} & \textbf{Equation} \\
    \hline \hline
    Euclidean distance between the shape model parameters vector for all
    landmarks $b$ and without the current landmark $b'$
    & \|b-b'\| \\
    \hline
    Average point-wise distance between the matched shape for all landmarks
    $\bar{x}$ and without the current landmark $\bar{x'}$
    & \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{3(m-1)}\bar{x}_i-\bar{x'}_i}{3(m-1)} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Landmark influence measurements.}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The equation column automatically switches to math mode and sets `\displaystyle`.

Comment: `array` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on some of the latex behaviour we're seeing here.

Comment: @karlkoeller: `\extrarowheight` requires package `array`. Currently `tabularx` loads package `array`, but this is an implementation detail and could change in future.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry for bothering...

Answer (score 3):

Redefine the tabularx column and sue a fixed width for the second column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{-5pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{-5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ |X|m{8em}| }
    \hline
    \textbf{Measurement} & \textbf{Equation} \\
    \hline \hline
    Euclidean distance between the shape model parameters vector for all landmarks $b$ and without the current landmark $b'$ & \[ \|b-b'\|\] \\
    \hline
    Average point-wise distance between the matched shape for all landmarks $\bar{x}$ and without the current landmark $\bar{x'}$ & \[ \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3(m-1)}\bar{x}_i-\bar{x'}_i}{3(m-1)}\]\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Landmark influence measurements.}\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]